# Poisson - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, statsmodels, poisson

Using the Poisson regression importing from `statsmodels.api` as sm.

I am doing something similar to this, but a different dataset.
https://timeseriesreasoning.com/contents/poisson-regression-model/

In my model:

```
y_train.shape = (52, 52)

X_train.shape = (52, 503)
```

I get an error when I run:

```
poisson_training_results = sm.GLM(y_train, X_train, family = sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
```

`"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (52,1,52) (52,503)"`

It just looks like it randomly adds '1' to y_train shape.

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Edit: CODE.

```
mask = np.random.rand(len(final_delta_df)) < 0.8
df_train = final_delta_df[mask]
df_test = final_delta_df[~mask]
print('Training data set length = '+str(len(df_train)))
print('Testing data set length = '+str(len(df_test)))
```

Training data set length=52
Testing data set length=12

```
expr = """deaths_sum ~ positive_auc + vax_pop + hospital_beds_avg + diabetes_prevalence + aged_70_older + stringency_avg + Avg_temp + Avg_UV_index + Avg_water_vapour + Delta_prop"""

y_train, X_train = dmatrices(expr, df_train, return_type = 'dataframe')
y_test, X_test = dmatrices(expr, df_test, return_type = 'dataframe')

poisson_training_results = sm.GLM(y_train, X_train, family = sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
```

Comment: y_train needs to be one-dimensional. GLM only handles univariate outcome, endog variables.

Comment: ok so how do i make it one dimensional?

Comment: I'm getting no errors. But I dont know how valid my data since I am not using counts? I have floats as data points.

Comment: Poisson estimates a  quasi-maximum-likelihood QMLE with continuous data which is consistent for an exponential mean function, but inference requires a sandwich covariance matrix like HC. I don't have a reference right now.

Comment: Here is a Stata link https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/  but there are several articles recommending using Poisson instead of linear regression with log(endog).

Comment: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2074

Comment: reference and example for Poisson: The Log of Gravity https://doi.org/10.1162/rest.88.4.641